# Unable to run Nodejs app on AWS Beanstalk

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have deployed NodeJS app on AWS Beanstalk. I am using AWS code pipeline for deployment from Github. After deployment when I am visiting URL, it's showing below error on web page:

> 502 Bad Gateway
> nginx/1.18.0

Below is my basic node code:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

const port = 3000 || process.env.PORT;

   app.get('/',(req,res) => {

   res.send("Hello there");
});

app.listen(port,(req,res) => {

 console.log(`App is running at ${port}`);
});
```

In below screen health of my environment is also showing severe. How can I resolve this?

[image: i]

Comment: Are there any specific errors showing up in Cloudwatch Logs?

Comment: Its showing these logs when I am click on causes button 1) 100.0 % of the requests are failing with HTTP 5xx.
2) ELB processes are not healthy on all instances.
3) ELB health is failing or not available for all instances.

Comment: I'm not a node guy per se but did you set up the healthcheck endpoint for the load balancer?

Comment: How can set it up as I am new to AWS could you help me out with that.

Comment: Sure. I posted an answer below. I'm starting at AWS in a few weeks as a Solutions Architect. So reach out with any other questions if the below doesn't help. Hit me up on twitter: @JackMarchetti

Comment: Let me test your solution and I followed u on twitter for future references.

Comment: Shouldn't this `const port = 3000 || process.env.PORT;` be opposite? i.e. `const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;`?

Answer (score 1):

Your load balancer needs a part of your application to "ping" which is sometimes called a heart beat or just a 'health check'.

This is usually just something that returns a HTTP 200 response to let the load balancer know that the host is healthy and can receive traffic.

I'm not a node.js guy but if you can create some endpoints like /health-check and just return an "ok" or HTTP 200 that will satisfy the need.

You can also have your health-check do something like check if the database connection is running as well. It's up to your specific use case.

Within beanstalk you would then designate /health-check as the URL endpoint for the load balancer to check.

Check out this link as well:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.healthstatus.html

Answer (score 0):

This is the logic error => `const port = 3000 || process.env.PORT;`

Try with this assignment => `const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;`