# Node JS app is crashing on AWS EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-code-deploy

I have deployed app on ec2 using codedeploy service but app is crashing and showing below error message:

```
Script at specified location: scripts/start_server failed to complete in 100 seconds
```

Below is my **appspec.yml** file:

```
version: 0.0
os: linux
files:
  - source: /
    destination: /tmp/
hooks:
  AfterInstall:
     - location: scripts/install_dependencies
       timeout: 100
       runas: root
  ApplicationStart:
     - location: scripts/start_server
       timeout: 100
       runas: root
```

**install_dependencies**

```
cd /tmp/

curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.34.0/install.sh | bash
. ~/.nvm/nvm.sh
nvm install node

npm install
```

**start_server**

```
cd /tmp/

node server.js
```

Someone let me know what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your deployment hangs because of this `node server.js`. This will start your app and that's it. It will never finish, so CodeDeploy timeouts waiting for that to finish.

One way to overcome the problem is to start your app through `systemd`. Thus you have to create a `systemd` unit file. There are many examples for that:

- [Running Your Node.js App With Systemd](https://nodesource.com/blog/running-your-node-js-app-with-systemd-part-1/)
- [Running Node.js on Linux with systemd](https://www.cloudbees.com/blog/running-node-js-linux-systemd)

Other ways could involve running your app using [pm2](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/) or [forever](https://github.com/foreversd/forever).

Comment: Thanks man its working fine now I have used PM2 but its working on `http://` port only and not on `https://`  even I have included `https://` in my security group to be access from anywhere.

Comment: @Digvijay Glad it worked .For https you need either proper ssl certificates setup with nginx on the instance or front it with load balancer.

Comment: @Digvijay No problem. You try to setup nginx or get load balancer (easier) and if have difficulties, please make new question with relevant info. For valid SSL cert you will need your own domain as well.

Comment: I have also tried node app deploying on aws beanstalk but its unaccessible and showing me errors here is the link for that there were some solution but that was not cleared to me. If u can help me out with that here is the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67508414/unable-to-run-nodejs-app-on-aws-beanstalk